# strange CAST() behaviour in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have got a table in DataBase. Table consists of two columns.
First column for DeliveryDate it has a type of DATETIME
Second column for DeliveryTime it has a type of VARCHAR

Here is a little example of table data

```
          DeliveryDate       -  DeliveryTime  
    2014-11-06 00:00:00.000  -     15:00
    2014-11-06 00:00:00.000  -     15:00
    2014-11-12 00:00:00.000  -     09:00
    2014-11-12 00:00:00.000  -     09:00
```

Table has 92 rows in it.

The goal is to make a query that concats DeliveryDate and DeliveryTime to a single DATETIME column

I make request like this

```
SELECT CAST((O.DeliveryDate + RIGHT(ISNULL(O.DeliveryTime,'00:00'),5)) AS DATETIME)
FROM MySuperTable
```

Query fails with error of invalid conversion from varchar

But if i make query with TOP for example TOP 92.

```
SELECT TOP 92 CAST((O.DeliveryDate + RIGHT(ISNULL(O.DeliveryTime,'00:00'),5)) AS DATETIME)
FROM MySuperTable
```

Query completes without errors.
Moreover TOP until 620 is ok nut TOP 621 again fails.
Please help to undestand how top logic works and whats the problem with my code

Comment: what is the output you got?? for SELECT TOP 92 CAST((O.DeliveryDate + RIGHT(ISNULL(O.DeliveryTime,'00:00'),5)) AS DATETIME)
FROM MySuperTable

Comment: You wrote that table has 92 rows. After that, you wrote you are selecting "top 621" records? So, how many records you have?

Comment: result of TOP 92 is like  2014-11-05 00:00:00.000 | 09:00 | 2014-11-05 09:00:00.000

Comment: As I said erlier I've got 92 records but I tried to set TOP for more then table rows count just for testing

Comment: It doesn't make a sense. If you have 92 records, selecting "Select top 621 ..." must give the same result as plain "Select ...".

Comment: @KenanZahirovic i see. But result is different and I'm tring to investigate why..

Comment: I just want to know table count Just post the result of: select count(*) from Table. and post the 621th record value (select top 621 * from table).

Comment: @Veera result just from production server so totaly I've got 93 row  in it. First select - 93 rows. Second select (TOP 621 - 93 rows)

Comment: Is the query works if you use select * from Tablename. only the cast fails in select * and  top 621 right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the Query Optimizer and how it optimizes the query. It most likely assumed it could rearrange a step or two to make things faster, not realizing that the data issue existed. This is why

- doing the `TOP 620` worked when there were only 92 rows as it was likely affecting the way the optimizer built the path on how to get the data
- separating the calculation to the UDF worked as it stopped the optimizer from being able to take whatever shortcut was causing the issue.

But UDFs are terribly slow.  Instead, try being more explicit in your query and not leaving it to SQL Server to implicitly convert a string (the time portion coming out of the `RIGHT` function) into a `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT O.DeliveryDate + CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT(ISNULL(O.DeliveryTime, '00:00'), 5))
FROM MySuperTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify query, try below query :

```
SELECT deliverydate
       + Cast(COALESCE(DeliveryTime, '00:00') AS TIME) AS DeliverDateTime
FROM   MySuperTable
```

although, we should use appropriate data type for columns. We have `TIME` datatype to store time.

Comment: Thanks for simplyfing advice! But the problem just the same. Without top I've got a cast error and no errors with it

Comment: similarly check minute part too. `select * from MySuperTable
where cast(parsename(REPLACE(DeliveryTime,':', '.'),2) as int) >= 24 or parsename(REPLACE(DeliveryTime,':', '.'),1) > 59`

Comment: this query returns empty result

Comment: second query also empty result

Comment: the same empty result

Comment: Just tried your's first query withoud declaring MySuperTable and just wrapping all in inner select statement. And got an error> Error converting nvarchar "8-23" to data type int

Comment: without declaring MySuperTable means? is this some kind of view or result of CTE? by the way, I tried my best to resolve your issue and last thing I got is check length of your data present in `DeliveryTime` column like `select COUNT(*) from MySuperTable where LEN(DeliveryTime) <> 5`. thanks for doing the things.

Comment: looks like you have some data with different kind of format 'h-mm'

Comment: according to your last query result is sero. Very very strange at all

Answer (score 0):

You have one empty row, it's probably last row in the table. 
Look for the row filled with NULL's.

EDIT: also look carefully in Time column, it could be some improper time or different formatting.

Comment: hm.. result retrun with number of rows so it's easy to detect any empty row in the end

Answer (score 0):

You have an improper time value.  The following should help you find the values:

```
select t.*
from MySuperTable t
where DeliveryTime not like '[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]';
```

You can use your method with a `case`:

```
select (case when DeliveryTime like '[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
             then CAST((O.DeliveryDate + RIGHT(ISNULL(O.DeliveryTime,'00:00'),5)) AS DATETIME)
        end)
```

If you were using SQL Server 2012+, you could use `try_convert()` as well.

EDIT:

Another possibility is that `DeliveryDate` has a time component.  What does this return?

```
select DeliveryDate
from MySuperTable
where DeliveryDate <> cast(DeliveryDate as date);
```

Comment: Just the same `where time not like '[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]';` makes result with zero rows

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but when I've separated `CAST` in a scalar function all begin to work fine. But very slow :(

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConcatDateAndTime]
(
    @DatePart DATETIME,
    @TimePart VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @DatePart + RIGHT(COALESCE(@TimePart,'00:00'),5)
END
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a function. Please see my answer :).