# Subquery casting as uniqueidentifier failes without Top() - MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, casting

The following query excludes rows by Id (of type uniqueidentifier) returned from a subquery, by trimming a NVARCHAR(MAX) field to a valid uniqueidentifier value, like *xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx*).

```
select * from tableA 
where Id not in(select cast (right(message, 36) as uniqueidentifier) from tableB)
```

But, the query above results in an error:
[image: Error without TOP]

The same problem occurs, if I use CONVERT.

The subquery

```
select cast (right(message, 36) as uniqueidentifier) from tableB
```

itself works.

My first attempt was to check, if there are some rows that are invalid by using TOP.
As I added a TOP to the query it just works fine in every case:

```
select * from tableA 
where Id not in (select top(n) cast (right(message, 36) as uniqueidentifier) from tableB)
```

The query works fine no matter what value I take for *n* (1, 1.000 or even 100.000)
I also thought about using TOP with ORDER BY. But when all rows are returned, using TOP(100000), the query works as intended.

Therefore, there are no NULL entries or not valid rows that are trimmed to an invalid uniqueidentifier value in TableB. The overall number of rows in TableB is about 13.000...

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971082/strange-cast-behaviour-in-sql-server-2008-r2), but it doesn't quite matches my problem.

Why does the query works after using top? I hope you can help me to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Because what ever (arbitrary) rows your subquery returns returns only values that can be converted. The *real* question is why are you storing `uniqueidentifier` values in a column that isn't a `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` should solve your issue (and checking for where `TRY_CONVERT` produces `NULL` should get you the invalid rows). The reason one query works and one doesn't is simply that the optimizer generates different plans whereby one query passes the invalid data through the `CONVERT` and the other one doesn't; this can happen regardless of how you formulate your `WHERE` since the optimizer feels free to physically rearrange things in spite of the logical semantics.

Comment: The problem isn't TOP. One of the `message` values isn't a valid GUID. `TOP` applies *after* the conversion. BTW using `nvarchar(max)` like this is a smell - `nvarchar(max)` isn't an `arbitrary-length string`, it's a `4GB-long string stored outside the table's data pages`

Comment: The best fix is to use a separate `uniqueidentifier` field to store the GUID, and populate it when the row is created. Next, change the `message` field to something appropriate.Even if you expect the `message` to contain more than 4K of data, it will be *easier* to extract any useful data into separate fields and avoid expensive parsing and casting after the fact

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: it's a common misconception, but values of `MAX` types are not stored outside the table pages unless the data actually exceeds 8000 bytes or the (non-default) `large value types out of row` is set with `sp_tableoption`. Of course that's not meant to imply proper typing isn't necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I always forget this. Because I rarely use `max` except for really large text. So, in the one case where `max` wouldn't cause a performance hit, it's unnecessary. I actually remember when `max` and in-page storage were the new thing

Comment: *"Therefore, there are no NULL entries or not valid rows"* simply not true. A `top` with no `order by` means it will just pick the same rows again and again. And `not in` on a nullable column will also cause problems. Just do a straight check `select * from TableB where try_cast(right(message, 36) as uniqueidentifier) is null`

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` and `try_convert()`:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where not exists (select 1
                  from tableB b
                  where a.id = try_cast(right(message, 36) as uniqueidentifier)
                 );
```